# Anyone else unable to listen to uncaughtErrorEvent when loaded by another swf?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, loaderinfo

When I try to access the `uncaughtErrorEvents` dispatcher when loaded directly, everything works well. But when I try the same code when loaded by another swf I get a reference error.

```
protected function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {
    trace("Flash version: " + Capabilities.version);
    try {
      loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener("uncaughtError", onUncaughtError);
      trace("YAY!");
    } catch (e:Error) {
      trace(e);
    }
}
```

Output when loaded directly (in browser):

```
Flash version: MAC 10,1,53,64
YAY!
```

Output when loaded by another "loader" SWF:

```
Flash version: MAC 10,1,53,64
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property uncaughtErrorEvents not found on flash.display.LoaderInfo and there is no default value.
```

If others can replicate this I'd be appreciative.

**EDIT**: Also have tried this with `stage.loaderInfo`, instead of just `loaderInfo`. Same issue...

Answer (score 1):

the loaderInfo of a loaded object is different from that of an initialised object, and content through a Loader class is delt with differently. in the documentation is states that you have to add the listener to uncaughtErrorEvents on the loader, not the loaderInfo assosiated with it:

> To detect uncaught errors that happen
>   in a loaded SWF, use the
>   Loader.uncaughtErrorEvents property,
>   not the
>   Loader.contentLoaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents
>   property.

[-livedocs link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo)

so presumably you have to either add it to the loader rather than the loaded or detect if loaded and then add it to parent or something instead. inelegant i know, but all i can think of to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

see this link: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4978

There are a bug in the Flash Player which affect the handler 
uncaughtErrorEvents on modules

If you register in Adobe's JIRA and vote, the bug will be repared sooner...

Answer (score 0):

I attached the event listener to the 'root', which worked for me:

```
sprite.root.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);
```

In the debug Flash Player this will still error, but in the non-debug version the error will appear in Flash Player's dialog box - and then the handler will respond. To stop the dialog box from appearing, add:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

so:

```
    private function onUncaughtError(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do something with this error
    }
```

I was using this in AIR, but I assume it works for standard AS3 projects too.